# Xcode save text

Tags: xcode, text, save, label

How can i save a label, then, if I close the app and open again it is still there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NSUserDefaults if the data is general preferences type data that won't cripple the app if the user prefs are wiped for any reason.

It depends on how vital the data is and how permanent you need to make the persistence.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best you can do is saving your data in a textfile